# Keep existing filename and add two characters at the end

Tags: pdf, rename

Hello stackoverflow community,

I've a folder called R and L. 
Both folders contain pdf files with the folowing syntax:

- date_vendor.pdf
- 20200302_hp.pdf

All files in the folder R should get the characters **_R** in its filename at the end:

- date_vendor_R.pdf
- 20200302_hp_R.pdf

All files in the folder L should get the characters **_L** in its filename at the end:

- date_vendor_L.pdf
- 20200302_hp_L.pdf

I simply tried it with the command rename, but that didn't work properly:

```
rename *_*.pdf *_*_L.pdf
```

Output in this case will be:
20200302_hp.pdf_L.pdf

Any suggestion how I can solve that with a batchscript or powershell?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the 'for' syntax. At the command shell if you type `help for` you will get lots of itneresting information to help you.

Something like :

```
for %s in (L/*.pdf) do ren %s %~ns_L.%~xs
```

and then

```
for %s in (R/*.pdf) do ren %s %~ns_R.%~xs
```

~n when applied to the variable filled in by for results in the full path and filename, but **not** the file extension. ~x applied to the variable results in just the file extension.